# Requests doing multiple commands

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello im new at requests module and i want do this missions with requests:

> 1-) Loging to my instagram account.

> 2-) Following target account from "target_accout"

I have this code for loging my instagram account with requests module:

```
#instagram scraping

import json
from datetime import datetime
from typing import BinaryIO
import requests

username = input("User Name: ")
password = input("User Password: ")
target_accout = input("Enter username to follow: ")

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
response = requests.get(link)
csrf = response.cookies['csrftoken']

payload = {
    'username': username,
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{password}',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

login_header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
    "x-csrftoken": csrf
}

login_response = requests.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=login_header)
json_data = json.loads(login_response.text)

if json_data["authenticated"]:

    print("login successful")
    cookies = login_response.cookies
    cookie_jar = cookies.get_dict()
    csrf_token = cookie_jar['csrftoken']
    print("csrf_token: ", csrf_token)
    session_id = cookie_jar['sessionid']
    print("session_id: ", session_id)
else:
    print("login failed ", login_response.text)
```

But i don't know how to do two different requests so i don't know how to do following my account as second command same time with loging.

How i can follow to target account after loging my own account? Im so noob at cookies and requests.

Comment: I don't know if this strategy will work, but I'll point out that you already have two requests: the first to get a CSRF token and the second to login and get a session id. Your third request (to follow an account) would come afterwards

Comment: @RohitChatterjee Exactly, do you have a idea or code example for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using requests.session() since this will automatically save any cookies returned during requests. This should make it easy keeping track of your logged in session.

So instead of doing

```
response = requests.get(link)
```

Instantiate a session first, and then use that to send the requests, like so.

```
session = requests.session() 
response = session.get(link)
```

And then just keep using that session for everything.

Comment: thanks but i need part of following system how i can do this?